# Focus on the PAIRS of letters

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**Replace the question marks with the correct letters and explain what two-word noun this puzzle is about.**

---

```
      FI              [][][][][][][][]
      IN              [][][][][][][][]
      TR        [][][][][][]
      GN      [][][][][][][]
      ??          [][][][][][][][][][]                    
      CH          [][][][]
      CO            [][][][][][]
```

Comment: Too bad the first two entries line up, otherwise I might have found a (red) herring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puzzle is about "noble gases".

> Country codes with their capitals:
>
> ```
> FI              HELSINKI
> IN              NEWDELHI
> TR           ANKARA
> GN          CONAKRY
> ??            XXXXXXXXXX
> CH            BERN
> CO             BOGOTA
> ```

> Among He, Ne, Ar, Kr, Rn, Og, Xe (Xenon) is missing, so the capital is LuXEmbourg and ??=LU.

Comment: Well done, just beat me to it!

Comment: Pairs is an anagram for paris hence the capitals

Comment: @PDT nice appointment, secret hint, but "capitals " is only one word.

Comment: @codewarrior0 thanks for editing into fixed font inside spoiler

Comment: That's it, well done!